# Integrate our Own Functions With api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

Salam.
I want to ask, how i will integrate my own Function with api.ai bot code.So it will pop-up a msg if my bot couldn't understand any question of users.And i will give the answer through my function. 
I need to do this process with api bot is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use webhooks feature for this https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook

In the case of webhook you will get a POST request with api.ai result and will have a chance to change it

Comment: how to access the parameters sent from api.ai inside the webhook?

Comment: I think you could get them from the received JSON https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook#section-format-of-request-to-the-service